# How can I remove a block which is in every page in Magento?

Tags: magento

I'm new in Magento and I just simply want to remove a block (I guess in XML) which is in the `header` , see this code :

```
<reference name="header">
<block type="cms/block" name="header_block">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>header_block</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Where, I mean in which file I will have to put the XML code to remove this block ? 
This block is in every page .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Can remove Remove any block in header first you can check what is name of Block for example: I just removed top.links from local.xml file

```
<default>
    <reference name="header">
        <remove name="top.links"><!--  you can add your block name -->
    </reference>
</default>
```

Which was added in page.xml

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
```

So this name block is removed